# Reload a portion of the webpage using ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Controller (called for loading a specific board):

```
public function getBoard()
{
    $role       = $this->session->userdata('role');
    $user_id    = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
    $board_id   = $this->input->post('board_id');

    if ($this->session->flashdata('first_board_id') !== null) 
    {
        $board_id = $this->session->flashdata('first_board_id');
    }

    $data['board_id']   = $board_id;
    $data['board_name'] = $this->Board_model->getBoardName($board_id);
    $data['columnData'] = $this->Column_model->getColumns($board_id);
    $data['rowData']    = $this->Row_model->getRows($board_id);
    $data['tasks']      = $this->Task_model->getTasks($board_id);
    $data['pendingSubtasks']   = $this->Task_model->countPendingSubtasks($data['tasks']);
    $data['finishedSubtasks']   = $this->Task_model->countFinishedSubtasks($data['tasks']);
    $data['boards']     = $this->Board_model->getBoards($role, $user_id);

        $this->load->view('templates/header',$data);
        $this->load->view('main_kanban', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer',$data);
}
```

From **templates/header.php**

```
<li class="custom-holder select-board">
        <label class="boostrap-select-label">BOARD:</label>
        <select class="selectpicker" title="CHOOSE BOARD" id='board_selection'>
            <?php 
        if (count($boards) > 0) {
          foreach ($boards as $b) {?>
              <option value="<?php echo $b->id; ?>"><?php echo $b->name; ?></option>
            <?php
          }
        }
  ?>
        </select>
</li>
```

From **func_board.js** (Loaded in the footer; called when dropdown selection is changed)

```
$('.select-board').on('change', '#board_selection', function() {
console.log('Changed board selection.');
var selected_board = $('#board_selection option:selected').val();

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: base_url + 'home', //configured this in routes.php
    data: { 'board_id' : selected_board },
    success: function(msg) {
        if (msg != 'failed') 
        {
            console.log('Loading board success!');
            $('.mainboard').load(base_url + 'home', {
                'board_id' : selected_board
            }); //mainboard is the parent div in main_kanban 
                 //that basically contains all the elements for the board
        }
        else 
        {
            console.log('Error >> ' + msg);
        }
    },
    error: function(xhr, error, errorThrown) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
        console.log(error);
    }
  });
});
```

I have a `select` or dropdown menu from which you can choose which board to view. However, as hinted by my code above, I'm using templates. Basically, when you click on a different board from the dropdown, it's supposed to load that board. The html for the board is in `main_kanban`. I don't think I can use `redirect` since there is data that I need to pass with the view.

I've tried jQuery's `load()` but I'm having problems with it. (There's a **New Task** button in each `<td>` as I'm using a table for the boards. When that New Task modal opens there is an option to select the **To Date** and **From Date**. When I use `load()` the date time picker doesn't show up. I'm using several scripts for the customization which are loaded in the `templates/footer.php` I have other select menus in the modal too. When ajax is finished those menus are empty.)
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the completion callback of `load()` to initialize plugins like date pickers

```
  var loadData = {'board_id' : selected_board};

  $('.mainboard').load(base_url + 'home', loadData , function(){
     // new html exists now .. initialize plugins or event listeners    
     $(this).find('.datepickerClass').datepicker({ /* options */})
  });
```

Comment: I have other `select` menus in the modal too. When ajax is finished those menus are empty.

Comment: No idea what that neeeds, not enough information provided

Comment: I see, not sure though if I should just paste the entire html here. But to make it short, I have a header, content, a footer. The content is dynamic, its content changes based on the selected board. I can't just redirect in the controller because the views need some data to be passed to them, so I have to use ajax (also to pass some POST var to the function). I have a function that gets the data needed to be loaded to the content. What would be the simplest way to achieve this?